# Rails simple captcha attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simplecaptcha

When I used in my rails 3 project gem "simple-captcha" (https://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha)  I had error in view by calling function <%= show_simple_captcha %>:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: key
```

Answer (score 2):

THIS WORKED FOR ME:

**Put this in an initializer (config/initializers/simple_captcha.rb)**

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  class SimpleCaptcha::SimpleCaptchaData < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_protected
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I was using form-based view code:

```
<%= f.simple_captcha(:label => "Enter letters from image above", :placeholder => "") %>
```

I think this was caused by the f referring back to my user model, which could
not reference the captcha attributes.  I dropped the form base and the problem
went away.  (Tried both solutions above, but they didn't work in my case.):

```
<%= show_simple_captcha(:label => "Enter letters from image above",
                        :placeholder => "") %>
```

Answer (score -2):

Solution: 
use alternative repository for rails 3 applications via

```
gem 'simple_captcha', :git => 'git://github.com/rubymaniac/simple-captcha'
```